# What is a System paper

Tags: publications, paper-submission

As I was going to submit a paper in one of the Elsevier's journal (Web Semantics), it asked me to select the [type of paper](http://www.elsevier.com/journals/journal-of-web-semantics/1570-8268/guide-for-authors#2001). The types include "research paper", "system paper!", "ontology paper", "position paper", "survey paper", "briefing paper".

I don't know what are they, and didn't find a document about them [except this](http://www.elsevier.com/journals/journal-of-web-semantics/1570-8268/guide-for-authors#2001) which doesn't tell much. I doubt if my paper is just a regular or research paper or a system paper.

In my paper I proposed a computer application which is a software system. however, it provides a solution for a problem. Does this make it a system paper!!!

Comment: Here's a list of ["tools and systems" papers](http://www.semantic-web-journal.net/tools_and_systems) from a different semantic web journal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [page you linked to](http://www.elsevier.com/journals/journal-of-web-semantics/1570-8268/guide-for-authors) provides a [PDF named *Author Information Pack*](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/journaldescription.cws_home/671322?generatepdf=true) (at the very top, right under the headline).

In that file, the different paper types are described. In particular, a *Systems Paper* is defined as follows:

> Widely adopted semantic systems and systems that generate a far above average amount of interest in the Semantic Web community, may be explained in systems papers. Systems papers are recommended to have 6 - 8 pages in double column format.